# Fermat's Little Theorem and graph cycle length

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a digraph with $\mathbb{Z}_n, (n$ : prime) as its vertex set. We can define a permutation on G by multiplication by $a$ for $GCD(a,n)=1$

And let $l$ be the least natural number such that $a^l \equiv a$ mod $n$

Prove that all cycles on G are of length $l-1$ except for the loop on $n$

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring this problem out. Does the permutation define the orientation of the digraph?

So I take cycles of length other than $n$ but I'm just not sure what to take.

Say I take a k length cycle. then $a^k \equiv x $ mod $n$ for some $x$ that isn't divisible by $n$ but I don't see where that gets me.